# How to compare an XML file to a device string in C#?

Tags: c#, xml

Sorry for the formatting - the device string is full of returns and newlines

I have this string from a device;

```
1) Port: 11 Phone: 18005555555  IP: 192.168.0.1\r\n\r 
2) Port: 11 Phone: 18005551234  IP: 192.168.0.1\r\n\r 
3) Port: 0     Phone: 0         IP: 0.0.0.\r\n\r 
4) Port: 0     Phone: 0         IP: 0.0.0.\r\n\r 
5) Port: 0     Phone: 0         IP: 0.0.0.\r\n\r\r\n
```

and I have this XML file that has the valid data I want to compare the string to.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Data>
  <USA>
    <Speed2G>
      <PhoneNumber1>
        <Port>11</Port>
        <Phone>18005555555</Phone>
        <IP>192.168.0.1</IP>
      </PhoneNumber1>
      <PhoneNumber2>
        <Port>11</Port>
        <Phone>18005551234</Phone>
        <IP>192.168.0.1</IP>
      </PhoneNumber2>
      <PhoneNumber3>
        <Port>0</Port>
        <Phone>0</Phone>
        <IP>0.0.0.</IP>
      </PhoneNumber3>
      <PhoneNumber4>
        <Port>0</Port>
        <Phone>0</Phone>
        <IP>0.0.0.</IP>
      </PhoneNumber4>
      <PhoneNumber5>
        <Port>0</Port>
        <Phone>0</Phone>
        <IP>0.0.0.</IP>
      </PhoneNumber5>
    </Speed2G>
  </USA>
</Data>
```

How do I go about this? I don't have any code per se because I don't know where to start. The values in the string need to match the innertext of the xml.

Comment: Sounds like you should start by parsing and reformatting one of the strings to the other format. Which direction you should go will most likely depend on what happens next and which format is easiest/fastest(?) to compare.

Comment: What did you find when you searched for "parse XML in .NET" or even "XML .NET"?

Answer (score 1):

The basic idea here would be to create a class called phone number that would look something like this:

```
public partial class PhoneNumber
{
    public int Ordinal;
    public int Port;
    public string Phone;
    public string IPaddress;

    public override bool Equals(Object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        PhoneNumber pn = obj as PhoneNumber;
        if ((object)pn == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return (this.Ordinal == pn.Ordinal) && (this.Port == pn.Port) && (this.Phone == pn.Phone) && (this.IP == pn.IP); 
    }
}
```

And then deserialize your data into `List<PhoneNumber>`.  For the XML, I would load the XML data into an `XDocument` and parse it that way, and for the text data you'll probably want it in some kind of `StreamReader`.  The code might like something like this...

```
public List<PhoneNumber> PhoneNumberFromXML(XDocument xd)
{
    List<PhoneNumber> lpn = new List<PhoneNumber>();
    foreach (XElement el in xd.Root.Descendants("Speed2G").First().Elements())
    {
        PhoneNumber pn = new PhoneNumber();
        //... logic to parse the individual elements into your class
        lpn.Add(pn);
    }
    return lpn;
}
```

And another method like

```
public List<PhoneNumber> PhoneNumberFromDevice(Stream deviceText)
{
    List<PhoneNumber> lpn = new List<PhoneNumber>;
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader)
    {
        while (sr.Peek() > 0)
        {
            string line = sr.ReadLine();
            PhoneNumber pn = new PhoneNumber();
            // parse line into phone number
            lpn.Add(pn); 
        }
    }
    return lpn;
}
```

Obviously the parsing logic is going to take some work here.  You might consider incorporating it into constructors for the class; you could also try to write a class that would more directly serialize to/from your XML using `XmlSerializer`, but that may be more effort than needed for this use case.

Answer (score 0):

Create Collection from text and collection from Xml than compare those collections.

Answer (score 0):

I would investigate de-constructing your XML message into Object attributes using xpath.